# Bug upload picture Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, status-declined, stack-overflow, profile-picture

I've got a bug while I'm trying to change my avatar on Stack Overflow.

When I want to change it, I've got a strange display bug.

After I successfully uploaded my avatar from my computer, nothing changed. I always have a grey square instead of my avatar.

[image: Screenshot]
<sub>(source: [toile-libre.org](http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1373451150.png))</sub>

**EDIT** : Mac OS 10.8.4, Firefox Beta 23

Comment: What browser? What OS?

Comment: Ah oops. Sorry about that one @martijn. Didn't get notified.

Comment: NP; I just stomped your edit and incorporated the one remaining spelling mistake you fixed but I hadn't. :-)

Comment: See [Which browsers are officially supported? And what else do I need?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56161/187824)

Answer (score 11):

We [do not support beta products](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71208/225020).